# HTML Is Set Correctly But Won't Display

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, onclick, click

According to the Console, everything is working as it should, so my only issue is that the html that the console indicates is set correctly is only displaying after the first on.("click") event, all the subsequent ones will fire and set the html correctly but oddly not display it.

Meaning, if I don't hit the Issues tab, I should see the error message for each tab I click, not just see it for the first one.

What am I missing?

**http://jsbin.com/xaguzujo/1/**

```
    $("#issuesandsettings a").on("click", function(event) 
{
event.preventDefault();
  console.log("Fire");
if ($(this).html() == $("#issuesandsettings").find(".submenu").children("li").children("a").eq(0).html())
{
$("#panel").css("margin-left", "0px");
$("#issuesandsettings").css("float", "left");
}
else
{
console.log("And a miss");
  $("#error2").html("Oops, that isn't the Issues or Settings tab!");
  console.log($("#error2").html());
setTimeout(function()
{
$("#error2" ).fadeOut( "slow" );
},1567);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first click will invoke this:
$("#error2" ).fadeOut( "slow" );

This function will hide the div. After that, if you want to show the error message, you need to invoke $("#error2").show();